# Azure Database Query Optimizer using View Indices

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure, azure-sql-database

SQL Server Enterprise Edition's query optimizer will use indices from a view to increase performance of a query even if the view is not explicitly referenced in the query, if applicable. Question: does Azure Database do the same thing? I know SQL Server Express does not do this, for example. I want to ensure I can still get the performance I need from the query optimizer when doing a sort on a joined table with a few million users (works great on enterprise edition but takes several seconds on express - bottle neck at the sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime last year (2012) Microsoft announced that the engine was the same between SQL Server and SQL Azure (now called Windows Azure SQL Database :/). So you will likely get the same behavior. Same performance may be another question. Windows Azure SQL Database is also keeping replicas in place in the event of hardware failure. You get the benefit of the secondary coming online in a fashion that is seamless to you. But, This does have a bit of a performance cost. Also, the SQL running in Windows Azure is running in a shared environment. It is pretty well documented that the performance is not the same as a local dedicated multi-processor machine with fast storage. It is a bit of an unfair comparison multi-user, multi-instance vs. dedicated. For many applications this is fast enough, but not all.